# sed: remove numbers from file

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to remove all words from a file that contain a number

### Attempt

`sed -r 's/\w*\d\w*//g' file.txt`

### Sample file.txt:

```
12.23 worda
01234 wordb
wordc
fe424 wordd 
a232efe424 worde 7
a232efe424 wordf wordg 7
a232efe424 wordh h5f
```

### Desired ouput:

```
worda
wordb
wordc
wordd
worde
wordf wordg
wordh
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sed oneliner

```
sed -r 's/[^[:space:]]*[0-9][^[:space:]]* ?//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the command
sed 's/[0-9]//g' filename